# Advantage of using bitwise shifting in constant 1 in java

Tags: java, android, bitwise-operators

in android source code, there is something like below. Is there any good reason to use bitwise shifting in this situation? Wouldn't be simpler just typing 1 ?

```
public static final int POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE = 1<<0;
```

What is the disadvantage of using like below or advantage of above?

```
public static final int POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE = 1;
```

Comment: I think this should just point out that bit zero is set. If there were other flag constants, they would have `1<<1`, `1<<2`, `1<<3` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was done not for performance but for maintenance of the code.

Upon compilation compiler evaluates constant expressions, and this constant will be stored as `1`

But in future, when this constant should be changed via shifting, the maintainer will just change `0` to another number in the source code.

Shift operator just shows to maintainer, that shift operation can be used for this constant in the future releases.

Comment: But what is the harm of making 1 and then change into 2, 3, 4 etc? Wouldn't be better that way? I didn't get the advantage to be honest.

Comment: I do not know the context of this code, maybe it is a bit-mask. And, for example, a maintainer will need to show properly, that sixth-bit should be masked or something like that. If there will be an already computed number, it would not be as readable as when there is masking for sixth-bit via shifting.

Comment: Actually, if the Android developers did change the constant, they would create a significant binary compatibility problem.  The constant is a **compile time** constant, and its value is hard-wired into all classes that are compiled against the `FragmentManager` API.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance advantage for either version.  In the first case, the `1<<0` expression is evaluated at compile time, and the Java and Dalvik bytecodes will actually just use a constant `1` ... in both case.

The real reason is to document that this is a "bit flag" value.  Writing the expression as `1<<0` is saying that the flag has bit zero set.

---

Note that this *does NOT* give the developers the option of changing the shifting in some future version.  `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` is a public compile-time constant, so changing it *could* lead to binary compatibility problems.  Specifically, code that is compiled against different versions of Android would have different values for the constant.  That could make apps non-portable across different Android releases; i.e. you would need different versions of apps for the different releases.